# Two functions with set mutual part for $x+y+z=0 and x^2+y^2+z^2=25$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Give an example of two different functions $f$ and $g$ which are continous on the space $\mathbb{R}^3$ and their common part is set:
$ \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x+y+z=0, x^2+y^2+z^2=25   \} $

and part of the graph $f$ is belowe the graph $g$ and the other part of the graph $f$ is above the graph $g$

I'm not looking forward for full solution, but please just for hint, because i don't know, how i can even start.

Comment: $\mathbb R^3$ is not a plane, it is $3$-dimensional space.  Are they supposed to be defined on $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$?  And what do you mean by "common part"?

Comment: interpreting common part as the the intersection of domains

Comment: in task it is written $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ but then x+y+z=0 will give a function actually. Thats why i considered it as $ \mathbb{R}^3 $. Common part means for me that $ x+y+z=0 v x^2+y^2+z^2=25 \implies f(x,y,z)=g(x,y,z) $

Comment: $f(x,y,z)=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-25)$ and $g(x,y,z)=h(x,y,z)f(x,y,z)$ where $g(x,y,z)$ is never zero.

Answer (score 0):

you can think on [image: this] over the same domain without the pink plane.

Comment: i find it as hint for finding 2 functions with one intersection. I am able to do such task. Problematic for me is that for two different sets, which intersection is not empty, they have to be equal.